# Minkowski operations on normed vector spaces. Closedness of set.

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a seemingly easy question, but I am having trouble grasping the solution:

Given a closed $B\subset X$ prove that given $\beta \in K$, 
$$\beta B:=\{\beta b: b\in B\},$$
is closed. $X$ is our normed vector space over $K$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recall the following characterization of closure via sequences:

> *Let $C\subseteq X$. The following are equivalent:*
>
> i) $x\in C^{-}$
>
> ii) $\exists \,(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq C$   such that  $x_n\longrightarrow x$

Now, let $\beta\in K$,  $\beta x\in\beta B$, so $x\in B$. As $B$ is closed there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq B$ such that converges to $x$.

It is straightforward to see that $(\beta x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq \beta B$ and $\beta x_n$ converges to $\beta x\in \beta B$, so the latter is closed.